# Problema con PHP composer en CMD de windows

Tags: php, windows, cmd, composer

tengo un problema al ejecutar la siguiente linea en la CMD de windows 10

```
php composer.phar require phroute/phroute
```

el problema es que no pasa nada, el cursos se queda en blink y la cmd no hace nada, no se que pueda ser, anexo imagen

[image: Error en CMD de Windows 10 64 bits]

Comment: en entornos windows el comando solo debería ser composer require phroute/phroute pues el comando que indicas es para entornos linux

Comment: El comando que me indicaste lo coloque pero no hace nada, apenas le doy enter es como si no hubiese puesto nada, me pone para insertar otro comando

Comment: tienes la instalación de composer de manera global en las variables de sistema?

Comment: tengo el mismo SO que tu y a composer en las variables de sisrtema como global, luego hice el comando como te indico y me funcionó sin problemas

Comment: En el path dices? no lo tengo, solo tengo para usar el comando php, como pongo la de composer?

Comment: este es la ruta que deberías tener en tus variables de entorno como global para que el comando como te digo funcione C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin solo revisa si la ruta es la misma que en tu computadora

Comment: No tengo esa carpeta "ComposerSetup" en mi carpeta de ProgramData

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80898/discussion-between-alfredo-and-darioxlz).